# node парсинг в цикле

Tags: javascript, request, node.js

```
SKU_list.forEach(function(item, i, SKU_list) {
  request(url.replace("change", item), function(error, response, body) {
    jsonfile.writeFile(item + ".json", response.body, function(err) {
      console.log(item);
    });
  });
});
```

Помогите пожалуйста, вот есть цикл, как мне делать запрос в нем?
Реквест без цикла работает нормально. Но когда я вставляю его внутрь *forEach* реквест возвращает *undefined*. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: где смотрели, что запрос стал возвращать _undefined_?

Comment: SKU_list что в нем? скинуть пример можете какие значения?